# How to hide or disable a button after a text equals to something

Tags: javascript, php

```
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * from complaintbl where username = 
   '{$_SESSION['username']}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['complain_title']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['complain_text']."</td>";
        echo "<td><input type=\"text\" id=\"Status\" class=\"form-control editField\" style=\"width:50px;\" name=\"Status\" value=\"".$row['Status']."\" readonly/></td>";
        echo '<td><a href="studenteditcomplain.php?cid='.$row['cid'].'"><button title="edit" id="edit_button" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil white"></span></button></a><a href="deletecomplain.php?cid=' . $row["cid"].';><button title="delete" type="button"  class="btn btn-default btn-sr"  data-confirm="Are you sure to delete this item?"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash white"></span></button></a></td>';
    }
    }
    else
    {
        echo  "</table>";
        echo  '<p class="a1"><b>You have no item. Please insert item</p>';
    }
    ?>
```

How do i disable or hide the button id="edit_button" if text id="Status"==YES 
I tried to google but the only working here is that only the first row hides the button from the table.

Comment: You aren't going to want to give every text box and every button the same ID. Add some kind of iterator to the IDs.

Comment: SO i should use class? can u provide a javascript example..

Comment: Side note: Did you know that what you're using now to query a database is dangerous? Do you not know about prepared statements, or do you not care if you use this online and then you find your database be deleted one day?

Comment: just make the IDs be something like "edit_button" . $row['cid'] so they are all different.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that you are not breaking that part out so you can use an `if` statement. Secondly, as a side, you need to parameterize your sql. thirdly, you have some invalid html and lastly, as noted in comments as well, you should have unique ids. It would also be helpful if you had indents:

```
<table>
<?php
# You should switch to the OOP version of mysqli, it is more straight-forward when it comes to binding and overall use, in my opinion
# It would be better to create a function and include it than do this type of syntax here. It's not wrong necessarily, it's just messy and harder to read
$sql   = "SELECT * from complaintbl where username = ?";
$query = $con->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['username']);
$query->execute();

if($result->num_rows > 0):
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['complain_title'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['complain_text'] ?></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="status form-control editField" style="width:50px;" name="Status" value="<?php echo $row['Status'] ?>" <?php if($row['Status'] == 'YES') echo 'readonly' ?> /></td>
        <td><a href="studenteditcomplain.php?cid=<?php echo $row['cid'] ?>"><button title="edit" type="button" class="edit_button btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil white"></span></button></a><a href="deletecomplain.php?cid=<?php echo $row["cid"] ?>"><button title="delete" type="button"  class="btn btn-default btn-sr"  data-confirm="Are you sure to delete this item?"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash white"></span></button></a></td>
    <!-- You need to end the row -->
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile ?>
<?php else: ?>
<!-- you should close the <b> tag -->
<p class="a1"><b>You have no item. Please insert item</b></p>
<?php endif ?>

<!-- Seems like you should end the table regardless if there are no rows -->
</table>
```